# Multipathing support

Tags: networking, server, multipath

I have 2 nics in ubuntu server, say for e,g NIC1 and NIC2. These are intended to serve netapp storage traffic simultaneously using iscsi . Multipathing is enabled. When we issue the multipath -ll, i am seeing only 2 paths rather it should be 4 paths. As per initial troubleshooting with netapp storage team, it seems the paths shown in multipath -ll are coming from NIC1, the other NIC2 paths are not visible. iscsiadm discovery have sessions established with both NIC's. Right now while we have done NIC failure testing from both server or storage side, we have not seen any packet drops and so storage team says this is OS issue. Also, our Solution architect believes that this is not the correct design having NIC's serving the traffic individually.

1. Our objective is to achieve the data/iscsi traffic to be served by both the NIC's so that highly sensitive apps/dbs hosted on the server will not have any downtime for any sort of failures in storage or server side. I believe i am missing something on the multipath configuration.
2. We also thought of having LACP with layer2, so that i can have both NIC's actively serving the traffic, but i am unsure if this is the best practice of enabling LACP with ISCSI or not.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you narrow the scope of this question to the part that you're currently stuck on?

Comment: @moo I am stuck on point #1

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have 2-ports NIC1 and 2-ports NIC2, if system shows NIC1 port1 and port2 formed multi-path that means your NIC1 port1 and port2 connect to the same LUN which is not an optimal configuration. Your configuration should be NIC1 port1 and NIC2 port1 connected to LUN1, then formed multi-path, NIC1 port2 and NIC2 port2 connected to LUN2 then formed another multi-path. Here's [doc](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-iscsi).